PyCUDA | Shared Matrix Multiplication with Phases | Unintuitive Error
I'm seeing an error which I am unable to explain.
I wrote a simple kernel for matrix multiplication that performs the following optimizations:

Coalesced Global Memory Access
Shared Memory loading in phases and computing result

This is the problem setup:
// Compute C = A*B
// A shape = (M, K) 
// B shape = (K, N) 
// C shape = (M, N) 
// Test for all sizes as (n, n) - n in  [16, 32, 64, 128, ..., 2048]

Some snippets from my code:
__constant__ float MAX_VALUE = 3.4028235e+38;

__global__ void sharedMemKernel(float *C, float *A, float *B, int M, int K, int N){
    /*
    Matmul between A(M*K) and B(K*N) to give C (M*N)
    Used shared memory optimization
    Each blocks loads required input tiles into shared memory
    computations are performed by reading from shared memory
    Final writes from threads are into global memory
    Assume square tiles of size blockDim.x = blockDim.y
    */
    extern __shared__ float sharedMem[];
    
    int Bsize = blockDim.x;
    
    // load inputs A,B in shared memory in phases
    // Assume that block is square
    
    // int phases = (int)ceil((float)K / Bsize);
    int phases = (K + Bsize - 1)/Bsize;

    float *CTile = sharedMem;
    float *ATile = CTile + Bsize*Bsize;
    float *BTile = ATile + Bsize*Bsize;

    // Ensure that shared memory allocated is enough to store all matrices
    size_t sharedMemSize = 3 * Bsize * Bsize * sizeof(float); 
    assert((char*)(BTile + Bsize * Bsize) - (char*)sharedMem <= sharedMemSize);


    // ensure CTile is all zeros
    CTile[threadIdx.y * Bsize + threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    __syncthreads();
    
    
    for(int p=0; p<phases; p++){
        //load A, B into shared memory
        
        loadIntoSharedMemoryColPhase(ATile, A, p, M, K);
        loadIntoSharedMemoryRowPhase(BTile, B, p, K, N);

        __syncthreads();

        float result = 0.0f;
        for(int i=0; i<Bsize; i++){
            //compute phase-wise matrix multiplication
            result += ATile[(threadIdx.y)*Bsize + i]*BTile[i*Bsize + threadIdx.x];
        }
        // Write result to output
        if (result > MAX_VALUE) {
            printf("Max value!!\n");
            result = MAX_VALUE;
        }
        CTile[threadIdx.y*Bsize + threadIdx.x] += result;
    } 
    if( (blockIdx.y*Bsize + threadIdx.y)<M && blockIdx.x*Bsize+threadIdx.x<N){
        C[(blockIdx.y*Bsize + threadIdx.y)*N + blockIdx.x*Bsize+threadIdx.x] = CTile[threadIdx.y*Bsize + threadIdx.x];
    }
}

__device__ void loadIntoSharedMemoryColPhase(float *Ashared, float *A, int colTileIdx, int ArowSize, int AcolSize){
    /*
    Load data from input A into shared memory Ashared - of size (blockDim.y, blockDim.x)
    Assume that thread block size is same as Ashared size
    Phases move across columns of input matrix A
    */
    const unsigned int RowIdx =  blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    const unsigned int ColIdx =  colTileIdx*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if(RowIdx<ArowSize && ColIdx<AcolSize) {
        Ashared[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = A[RowIdx*AcolSize + ColIdx];
    }
    else{
        Ashared[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    }
    // Debug outptus
    // if(blockIdx.x==0 && blockIdx.y==0 && threadIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.y==0){
    //     printf("loaded value(%f) from A[%d][%d]\n",A[RowIdx*AcolSize + ColIdx],RowIdx,ColIdx);
    // }
}

Here are interesting errors that I see:

Without checking if result is beyond MAX_VALUE, I see that matrices of size 64x64 randomly differ from the CPU output used to test. Matrices beyond that - 128, 256, 512, etc.. always give an error.

When I had reduced the block size to (4, 4) instead of the original (32, 32), all tests passed!


This is unclear because of the following reasons:

In my experience the floating point issues that arise in a GPU should arise in the CPU as well and they outputs should be "equally" wrong. Why did the condition help pass the 64x64 test case?
I found a relevant source here: PyCUDA precision of matrix multiplication code that potentially makes it clear. It would make sense if my CPU code is performing this clipping by default.

Why is the block size deciding the result of my computation at all? If SMs do not have enough resources, would the resource manager not wait until enough resources are available for execution? What could the possible reason for this solution to work be? I tested this without any intuition and fail to explain this behavior.


Adding python test code:
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

BLOCK = (4, 4, 1)  # Use a tuple of integers for BLOCK dimensions


def GRID(M, N):
    return (int(np.ceil(M / BLOCK[0])), int(np.ceil(N / BLOCK[1])),
            1)  # Return a tuple of integers for GRID dimensions


def get_random_matrices(M, K, N):
    A = np.random.random((M, K)).astype(np.float32)
    B = np.random.random((K, N)).astype(np.float32)
    C = np.random.random((M, N)).astype(np.float32)
    return A, B, C


def get_ABC_gpu(A, B, C):
    A_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(A)
    B_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(B)
    C_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(C)
    return A_gpu, B_gpu, C_gpu


def load_kernel(kernel_path='./matmulKernels.cpp'):
    with open(kernel_path, 'r') as f:
        kernel = f.read()
    kernel = r'{}'.format(kernel)
    return SourceModule(kernel)


def matmul_gpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, fname='naive', shared=False):
    A_gpu, B_gpu, C_gpu = get_ABC_gpu(A, B, C)
    mod = load_kernel()
    func = mod.get_function(fname)
    if (not shared):
        func(C_gpu, A_gpu, B_gpu, M, K, N, block=BLOCK, grid=GRID(M, N))
    else:
        SHARED_MEM_SIZE = int(BLOCK[0] * BLOCK[1] * 3
                              * np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize)
        func(C_gpu, A_gpu, B_gpu, M, K, N, block=BLOCK, grid=GRID(M, N),
             shared=SHARED_MEM_SIZE)
    C = C_gpu.get()
    return C


def matmul_withtranspose_gpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, fname='naive', shared=False):
    A_gpu, B_gpu, C_gpu = get_ABC_gpu(A, B.T, C)
    mod = load_kernel()
    func = mod.get_function(fname)
    if (not shared):
        func(C_gpu, A_gpu, B_gpu, M, K, N, block=BLOCK, grid=GRID(M, N))
    else:
        SHARED_MEM_SIZE = int(BLOCK[0] * BLOCK[1] * 3
                              * np.dtype(np.float32).itemsize)
        func(C_gpu, A_gpu, B_gpu, M, K, N, block=BLOCK, grid=GRID(M, N),
             shared=SHARED_MEM_SIZE)
    C = C_gpu.get()
    return C


def matmul_cpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, transpose=False):
    Ashape = A.shape
    Bshape = B.shape
    if (not transpose):
        assert (Ashape[1] == Bshape[0])
        C = np.matmul(A, B)
    else:
        assert (Ashape[1] == Bshape[1])
        C = np.matmul(A, B.T)
    return C


def valid_check(M, K, N, fname='naive', verbose=False, shared=False,
                transpose=False):
    A, B, C = get_random_matrices(M, K, N)
    if (transpose):
        C_gpu_comp = matmul_withtranspose_gpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, fname=fname,
                                              shared=shared)
    else:
        C_gpu_comp = matmul_gpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, fname=fname, shared=shared)
    C_cpu_comp = matmul_cpu(A, B, C, M, K, N, transpose)
    try:
        assert (np.allclose(C_cpu_comp, C_gpu_comp))
        print("Valid computation!")
        return 1
    except Exception:
        if (verbose):
            return 0
        else:
            raise Exception("CPU and GPU results do not match!")


# sizes = 2**np.arange(4, 12).astype(np.int32)
sizes = np.array([1235, 257]).astype(np.int32)
num_exps = 1
for i in range(num_exps):
    TRANSPOSE = False
    for size in sizes:
        M, K, N = size, size, size
        print("*"*50)
        print(f"Testing M = {M}, K = {K}, N = {N}, transpose={TRANSPOSE}")
        valid = valid_check(M, K, N, fname='sharedMemKernel', shared=True,
                            verbose=True, transpose=TRANSPOSE)
        if (valid == 1):
            print("\033[32mTest passed!\033[0m")
            print("*"*50)
        elif (valid == 0):
            print("\033[31m.....FAILED!.....\033[0m")
            print("*"*50)

Addition device func:
__device__ void loadIntoSharedMemoryRowPhase(float *Ashared, float *A, int rowTileIdx, int ArowSize, int AcolSize){
    /*
    Load data from input A into shared memory Ashared - of size (blockDim.y, blockDim.x)
    Assume that thread block size is same as Ashared size
    Phases move across rows of input matrix A
    */
    const unsigned int RowIdx =  rowTileIdx*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    const unsigned int ColIdx =  blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if(RowIdx<ArowSize && ColIdx<AcolSize) {
        Ashared[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = A[RowIdx*AcolSize + ColIdx];
    }
    else{
        Ashared[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
    }
    // Debug outptus
    // if(blockIdx.x==0 && blockIdx.y==0 && threadIdx.x==0 && threadIdx.y==0){
    //         printf("loaded value(%f) from B[%d][%d]\n",A[RowIdx*AcolSize + ColIdx],RowIdx,ColIdx);
    //     }
}



The issue posed is totally unrelated to the reason behind this behavior.
In the setup, we perform matrix multiplication for single-precision numbers on both the GPU and CPU. The test is performed by comparing the outputs of CPU and GPU. While this seems reasonable, both are different machines and hence will have a different computational accuracy because of floating point limitations. The difference scales with input matrix size because the floating point error difference between the machines accumulates.
Another thing that can be explain now is why reducing block size led to a test case passing. This is because for a reduced block size, the errors produced are within accepted bounds. But this does not still work for bigger inputs because the computation by a single thread requires it to scan an entire row and column, each of which scales with input size.
MAX_VALUE:
This behavior is still not obvious. No computation goes beyond fp limit. So I am not sure how this can be explained.
